# What user role in App Store Connect is required to enable auto-signing in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

There is no information about certificates of provisioning profiles in the [Role permissions list](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve5f9a89d7). We already have tried App Manager and Developer, they both don't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be the team agent if you want to use the auto-signing feature. There is only one team agent permitted per app development team.

Comment: But Admin is also able to create provisioning profiles: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ It doesn't work?